# Как обозначить "больше ... но меньше ..." в discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord

У меня есть рулетка на монеты, там падает рандом число, сейчас у меня: если число >= 60 == победа, если число < 60 == проигрыш. (падает число от 1 до 100) Я хочу сделать чтобы падало число от 1 до 105, если падает число > 100 == победа x3. Но проблема в том что когда падает число, например 103 у меня выходит 2 окна (embed) что я выиграл при условии (random >= 100) и (random >= 60), получается мне надо пофиксить (random  >= 60) чтобы было random >= 60 НО < 100, как это записать на языке discord.js?

if (random < 100 || random >= 60) не работает

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 105) + 1;

  let bal = parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins); // Convert user's balance to number type

  if (bal < parseInt(args[0])) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Недостаточно монет!`)

  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Укажи ставку!`)

  if (random >= 100) {

  let tri = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
  .addField(`Победа!   `, `Выпало число: ${random}`)
  .setColor("#FDFF49")
  message.channel.send(tri)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) + parseInt(args[0]) + parseInt(args[0]) + parseInt(args[0])
    }
  };

  if (random < 100 || random >= 60) {

  let win = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
  .addField(`Победа! `, `Выпало число: ${random}`)
  .setColor("GREEN")
  message.channel.send(win)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) + parseInt(args[0])
    }
  };

  if (random < 60) {

    let lose = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
    .addField(`Проигрыш! `, `Выпало число: ${random}`)
    .setColor("#CB2E2E")
    message.channel.send(lose)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) - parseInt(args[0])
    }
  }
 };

module.exports.help = {
  name: "flip"
}
```

Comment: Вместо `||` => `&&`

Comment: Да всё спасибо, уже сделал